# deployR cannot open the connection

Tags: azure, deployr

I have set up `deployR` on an Azure VM, and have logged in as the `testuser` which comes as default with the installation.

Upon running the `ccFraudScore.R` model, I get the following error:

```
> if(!exists('fraudModel')){load('fraudModel.rData')}
Console Error cannot open the connection
API Error cannot open the connection
```

I also get the same error on my own scripts when trying to `load` or `read.csv` data, either from the same folder as the script, or using the `deployrExternal()` function, with a file to read in the appropriate folder in here: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\DeployR-<version>\deployr\external`.

I have set all the inbound Windows Firewall rules to "public" and enabled them, as described in the install documentation.

Please could anyone point me in the direction of where to look next?

**Update**

Thanks to @warmoverflow, I looked at the diagnostics and the app logs, and it appears everything is configured correctly, and the updated Microsoft installation guide.

If I log in to `<IP Address>:<Port>/deployr/landing` as administrator, then go to `Administration Console` > `The Grid`, I can edit the `External directory configuration` `Storage Context`, which by default is `/deployr/external/data`, as expected from the installation guide.

However, the problem persists.

**Temporary Fix**

As a temporary fix, I use a full file path to reference any other scripts or data files I need to use, and this works, as follows:

```
> if(!exists('fraudModel')){load('C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\DeployR-8.0.5\\deployr\\external\\repository\\testuser\\example-fraud-score\\fraudModel.rData')}
```

Note that I have not edited the above file path from installation.

Comment: Try to look at the log files of DeployR and see what's happening on the backend, but first of all, run the diagnostic and see if everything works.

Comment: It appears that you are using the enterprise edition of DeployR but referring to the documentation of the open source edition. The guide for the enterprise edition is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/deployr-install-on-windows