# Script test seems to not have correct working directory

Tags: microsoft-r, deployr

I am trying to see if I can get code examples to run in my user account, rather than the `testuser` account.  To that end, I did the following:

- I have created a folder `example-fraud-score` under my DeployR user account (not the `testuser` as laid out in the tutorial, found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/deployr-data-scientist-getting-started )
- uploaded the contents of `analytics/` from the tutorial to the `example-fraud-score` directory on the DeployR server.
- Attempted to run the file `ccFraudScore.R`, contents here: https://github.com/Microsoft/js-example-fraud-score-basics/blob/master/analytics/ccFraudScore.R using the 'Test' tab on the right after clicking on the filename in DeployR.

When I do, I get the error:

```
Connecting to 172.31.232.190:8000
3:53:26 PM Stream Connect matthew.pettis connection established, waiting for an event...
> require(deployrUtils)
> deployrInput("{\"name\": \"bal\", \"render\":\"integer\", \"default\": 5000, \"min\" : 0, \"max\": 25000 }")
> deployrInput("{\"name\": \"trans\", \"render\":\"integer\", \"default\": 12, \"min\" : 0, \"max\": 100 }")
> deployrInput("{\"name\": \"credit\", \"render\":\"integer\", \"default\": 8, \"min\" : 0, \"max\": 75 }")
> if (!exists("fraudModel")) {
+ load("fraudModel.rData")
Console Error cannot open the connection
API Error cannot open the connection
```

I tried following the post here to troubleshoot, but I could not find where my directory was: [deployR cannot open the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901455/deployr-cannot-open-the-connection)

When I used the script to look for the working directory (and list contents), I see:

```
> require(deployrUtils)
> getwd()
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~2/DEPLOY~1.0/rserve/workdir/conn2209460"
> list.files(getwd())
[1] "DeployREngineSource.r" "unnamedplot001.png"
```

This seems like the wrong directory to be using.  When I try to hunt around for my directory for my user, I can't seem to find it.  My DeployR version is 8.0.0.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Is that the remote directory (the second box)?
If so, why don't you call `setwd()`?